# async await wrong order of execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get a grip of the async await pattern. Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) example, I implemented
this small program:

```
private async void asynchWork()
{
    // Line 1
    Task<string> readTask = asynchAwaitWork();

    // Line 2
    synchWork();

    // Line 3
    string result = await readTask;

    // Line 4
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
    Debug.WriteLine("The End");
}
private void synchWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SynchWork For i : " + i);
        Thread.Sleep(750);
    }
}

private async Task<string> asynchAwaitWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("A-SynchWork For i : " + (i+111));
        Thread.Sleep(750);
    }

    return "finished";
}
```

I expected that Line 1 is executed, then Line 2 and Line 4 will have to wait until Line 3 is finished and returns a string.
But looking at the output the `synchWork` method is executed after the `asynchWork` method.

> A-SynchWork For i : 111
>
> A-SynchWork For i : 112
>
> A-SynchWork For i : 113
>
> A-SynchWork For i : 114
>
> A-SynchWork For i : 115
>
> ...
>
> A-SynchWork For i : 125
>
> SynchWork For i : 0
>
> SynchWork For i : 1
>
> SynchWork For i : 2
>
> SynchWork For i : 3
>
> SynchWork For i : 4
>
> finished
>
> The End

I expected the `synchWork` method to be executed in the time when the `asynchWork` method is buisy and waits in Line 3 for the result.
What did I misunderstood in the example? Or is it just that the output of `Debug.WriteLine` is executed in the end sequentially but the real order of working is according to my expectations?

EDIT:
With the help of the comments and answers I learned:

- Don't ignore the warning and research their meaning ;)
- using the `await` keyword allows to wait for the result of an operation which is executed by a created `Task` inside the method.

EDIT 2:

- But the Task has to be started! otherwise there will be no parallel processing and the compiler will chase it through the main thread and Line 3 has actually only a blocking function for Line 4 not more.

since `Thread.Sleep(750)` is only a simulated work and I don't really need `Delay` this also works:

```
private async Task<string> asynchAwaitWork()
{
    await Task.Run(()=> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("A-SynchWork For i : " + (i+111));
                Thread.Sleep(750);
            }
            });
    return "finished";            
}
```

Thank you very much. I learned a lot :)

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning for `asynchAwaitWork`, it gives a clue to why it did not work

Comment: @ScottChamberlain await is missing it says. Therefore it will be executed synchronously. I just don't quite understand why from this little information.

Comment: @MongZhu Then do some research on that warning.  There's lots of information out there on it.

Comment: @Servy good tip, am doing it right now.
using await creates a task which can run in parallel, if I don't use it, then the compiler will chase it through the main thread! am I right?

Comment: Not quite.  Using `await` does NOT create a task which can run in parallel.  `await` **asynchronously waits** for a task to complete.  Await and async do not **make** anything asynchronous. **They allow you to work more easily with methods that are already asynchronous**.  Again: no new asynchrony is *created* by await or async.  You have to *already* have an asynchronous operation to await.

Comment: *"the await keyword creates a Task and allows for parallel processing"* I think you may be getting the wrong idea, while that statement is technically true it is not always true. Run your code example from inside a app with a UI from the UI thread. You will see the code is not run in parallel because all of the code is run on the single UI thread.

Comment: silly me... of course it does not create a `Task`.. I create the `Task` ... stupid. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I ran the code but with the newly edited `asynchAwaitWork` method. In the button event of the GUI I just execute `asynchWork();` and it runs in parallel. What did I wrong?

Comment: I did not see the Task.Run in the edit last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking only at your main program:

When line 3 has executed, you are guaranteed that the Task you got in line 1 has *finished* executing whatever is inside it.

At line 2, you have no guarantees that the task has started executing or that it has finished. You don't know whether it'll run in parallel or not. All you know is that there is a Task that could be scheduled to execute.

The implementation of your task you created in the function `asynchAwaitWork` is completely synchronous. That implementation detail causes it to be completely done printing stuff when it returns the Task that will eventually (which in this case is immediately) return a string.

Note that the Task you created does not print anything. Printing your "A-SynchWork For i" messages in the current implementation is a side-effect of *creating* your task.

Comment: great explanation! so does it mean that in `asynchAwaitWork` the part: `async Task<string>` results in the creation of a task but it is never run in parallel because there is no line of code that says `Start(...)` or `Run(...)`. That's why it also never prints anything?=! when `asynchAwaitWork` reaches the return statement it assigns the return value to the Task which is passed to `result ` in Line 3.
The Last part of your answer was really enlightening!

Comment: More discussion is probably better for a chat format. But your `asynchAwaitWork` does the equivalent of `console.WriteLine("this is a side effect"); return Task.FromResult("finished")`. Awaiting that task has nothing to do with the WriteLine preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

just replace 
`Thread.Sleep(750);` to `await Task.Delay(750);` at asynchAwaitWork
Thing is that asynchAwaitWork start working in main thread. Asyncronious work - this is for continuations. Using await keyword, you creating continuation, thats why it start working parallel.
Also add current thread Id to your output to see, what happens. Example:

```
private async void asynchWork()
{
    // Line 1
    Task<string> readTask = asynchAwaitWork();

    // Line 2
    synchWork();

    // Line 3
    string result = await readTask;

    // Line 4
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
    Debug.WriteLine("The End");
}
private void synchWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SynchWork For i : " + i + " and thareadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(750);
    }
}

private async Task<string> asynchAwaitWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("A-SynchWork For i : " + (i + 111) + " and thareadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(750);
        //Thread.Sleep(750);
    }

    return "finished";
}
```

as was noticed, Task.Delay(750) will use same sync context, if it is created. 
Fore example, if you are run code from WPF

```
[STAThread]
void Main()
{
    var window = new Window();
    window.Loaded += (s, e) => {
        asynchWork();
    };
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

you will see that all happens in same thread.
so, be aware about that and you can use `await Task.Delay(750).ConfigureAwait(false);` to avoid this.

Comment: If this is run in a console app they will run in parallel, but if you run this in a situation where the `SyncronisationContext.Current` is set it will run the first `asynchAwaitWork` then all of the `synchWork` then the rest of the `asynchAwaitWork`. You need to do `await Task.Delay(750).ConfigureAwait(false);` or do `Task<string> readTask = Task.Run(() => asynchAwaitWork());`

Comment: yep, Task.Delay(750) will continue with current context. So, if we run it in WPF app (for example) in UI thread, continuation will be run in UI thread. Thank you, @ScottChamberlain, you are right.

Comment: @tym32167 "Using await keyword, you creating continuation" why exactly? could you elaborate?

Comment: @MongZhu not sure that Im able to completely describe how it works. But you have to know that await and async - it is not processor or IL instructions, compiler thransform this keywords to some constructions. To deeply understand this you can try this https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation

Comment: thanks for the link. I already grasped a lot in the last hour. reading your link now